# How to escape the ' character in sas?

Tags: sas

I have this variable in sas called `saying`. This variable contains the value `Hello 'n Hi`

I have written the following code

```
data work.queryData;
 set work.actualData;
 if saying='Hello 'n Hi' then saying2='Hello and hi';
run;
```

How do I escape the `'` character in sas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the percent symbol to escape the single quote:

```
'Hello %'n Hi'
```

Comment: also, if you ever have this issue with a macro, use %BQUOTE. Spent about a day trying to figure that one out....

Comment: @EvanVolgas thank you so much i tried anything but nothing worked! i have to create a macro variable using `sql select into` with an input dataset name saved inside a macro variable, so this is how to do it `where libname = 'WORK' and memname = %upcase(%bquote('&dsin2'))`

Answer (score 6):

Or double it... works with single and double-quotes.

```
data _null_ ;
  x = 'Hello ''n Hi' ;
  y = "Hello. He said ""Hello"" then ""goodbye""" ;
  put x= ;
  put y= ;
run ;

x=Hello 'n Hi
y=Hello. He said "Hello" then "goodbye"
```